# Get clicked Array Item for Navbar / Submenu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Attempting to create a SubMenu for My NavBar I can't seem to get the the appropriate on Array Data Click.

I've tried utilizing the CSS to hide the menu. Among setting a state. I'm at a loss and not really sure how to move forward. I'm a n006 and starting to feel like I'm over my head. If you can please help, it would be greatly appreciated.

http://development.wr09.org/

I'd like the submenu to be produced after index[1] is selected "Blaine County Life RP" Sub Menu item is defined in the array as menu.

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MenuItems } from "./MenuItems"
import { Button } from "../Button/Button"
import './Navbar.css'
import logo from './navbar_images/bclrp_logo.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Iframe from 'react-iframe';

class Navbar extends Component {
    state = { clicked: false }
    bclrp = { clicked: false }
    
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })
        this.setState({ clicked: !this.bclrp.clicked })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <nav className="NavbarItems">
                    <h1 className="navbar-logo"><img src={logo} alt =""width="90" height="90"></img>
                        </h1>
                    <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                        {MenuItems.map((item, menu, index) => {
                            if (item.menu == 'main') { return (
                            
                                <Link to = {item.url}>
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <a className={item.cName}>
                                    {item.title}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                </Link>
                            )}
                            
                            else if (item.menu == 'bclrp' && this.bclrp.clicked ){ return (
                                <Link to = {item.url}>
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <a className={item.cName}>
                                    {item.title}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                </Link>
                            )}
                        })})
                    </ul>
                    
                    <Button>Join Here</Button>
                    
                </nav>
                <div className="loadingvideo">
                    <Iframe url="http://development.wr09.org/home_page_loading/loading.html"
                    width="100%"
                    height="700"
                    id="myId"
                    className="loadingvideo"
                    display="initial"
                    position="relative"
                    allowFullScreen="true"
                    
                />     
                </div>
            </div>
            
        )
        
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

**MenuItems.js**

```
export const MenuItems = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        url: '/home',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        menu: 'main'

    },
    {
        title: 'Blaine County Life RP',
        url: '/bclrp',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        menu: 'main'
    },
    {
        title: 'Community Streamers',
        url: '/streamers',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        menu: 'main'

    },
    {
        title: 'Community Servers',
        url: '/servers',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        menu: 'main'

    },

    {
        title: 'Resources',
        url: '/resources',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        menu: 'main'

    },
    
    {
        title: 'Button',
        url: 'http://discord.gg/wr09',
        cName: 'nav-links-mobile'

    },

    {
        title: 'Life',
        url: '/life',
        cName: 'sub-nav-links',
        menu: 'bclrp'

    },
    {
        title: 'Rules',
        url: '/rules',
        cName: 'sub-nav-links',
        menu: 'bclrp'

    },
    {
        title: 'Information',
        url: '/information',
        cName: 'sub-nav-links',
        menu: 'bclrp'

    },
    {
        title: 'FAQ',
        url: '/faq',
        cName: 'sub-nav-links',
        menu: 'bclrp'

    },
]
```

Comment: Still hoping for help, Please and Thank you